#  where T: <interface> into where T: class gives cs0452

Tags: c#, generics

I have

```
public static void SecureTcpRpc<InterfaceType>(string uri, 
                                               Action<InterfaceType> action) 
                                              where InterfaceType : class;
```

Then I use that here

```
 private static AuthorizedActionResult 
                RunChannelAction<T>(IEnumerable<string> uris, 
                                    Func<T, AuthorizedActionResult> actionFunc)
                                    where T : IPingable
            {
                    WcfClient.SecureTcpRpc<T>....
```

THe compiler does not like that I have constrained T to be IPingable. I dont see why it objects. IPingable is a reference type, so it matches the constraint on the SecureTpcRpc method. But the compiler says 'T must be a reference type'

Comment: What is relation of this two functions?

Comment: structs (value types) can implement interfaces too.

Comment: @Cameron - aha , I always forget that

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you need the "class" constraint on the `AuthorizedActionResult` function also for it to work.

```
where T : class, IPingable
```

Comment: yup I worked that out after Camerons comment (class comes first tho)

Answer (score 1):

Should the second one be generic? If it is for interface type, it should be something like:

```
private static AuthorizedActionResult RunChannelAction(
  IEnumerable<string> uris, 
  Func<IPingable, AuthorizedActionResult> actionFunc)
        {
                WcfClient.SecureTcpRpc<IPingable>....
```

Comment: +1 This was my initial reaction too. A generic type parameter is completely unnecessary here.