# C# How to access member of generic type in a generic class?

Tags: c#, generics

```cs
    public class DS2DbContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<DocumentFileData> DocumentFileData { get; set; }
        public DbSet<WatermarkFileData> WatermarkFileData { get; set; }
        public DS2DbContext(DbContextOptions<DS2DbContext> options) 
            : base(options) { }
        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }
    }

    public class FileDataController<T> : ODataController where T : class
    {
        private readonly DS2DbContext _context;
        private readonly ILogger<FileDataController<T>> _logger;

        public FileDataController(DS2DbContext dbContext,
                                  ILogger<FileDataController<T>> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _context = dbContext;
        }

        [EnableQuery]
        public SingleResult<T> Get([FromODataUri] Guid ID)
        {
            var result = _context.Set<T>().Where(i => i.ID == ID);
            // Error CS1061: 'T' does not contain a definition for 'ID'
            // and no accessible extension method 'ID' accepting a
            // first argument of type 'T' could be found
            return SingleResult.Create(result);
        }
    }
```

How do I properly (and if possible, elegantly) access members of variables with type T and get their values?

**Update**

When I use an interface like this:

```cs
    public class FileDataController<T> : ODataController where T : IFileData
    {
        private readonly DS2DbContext _context;
        private readonly ILogger<FileDataController<T>> _logger;

        public FileDataController(DS2DbContext dbContext,
                                  ILogger<FileDataController<T>> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _context = dbContext;
        }

        [EnableQuery]
        public SingleResult<T> Get([FromODataUri] Guid ID)
        {
            var result = _context.Set<T>().Where(i => i.ID == ID);
            // Error CS0452: The type 'T' must be a reference type in
            // order to use it as parameter 'TEntity' in the generic
            // type or method 'DbSet<TEntity>'            
            return SingleResult.Create(result);
        }
    }
```

I am getting an error when calling _context.Set().

What I have come up with is

```cs
    var result = _context.Set<T>()
        .Where(x => (Guid) x.GetType().GetProperty("ID").GetValue(x) == ID);
```

But this looks horribly complicated.

**The story behind this**

is that I have to store data of the exact same structure in two different database table depending on the data's semantics (requirements document or watermark). Since I am doing Blazor, code first, I need to have two different classes for this to make it correctly create two tables and handle them via two different controllers. However, these controllers share the exact same code and the exact same underlying data structure. Here is a simplified example just implementing an ID:

```cs
    public interface IFileData
    {
        public Guid ID { get; set; }
    }

    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
    public class FileData : IFileData
    {
        [Key]
        public Guid ID { get; set; } = Guid.Empty;
    }

    public class DocumentFileData : FileData { }

    public class WatermarkFileData : FileData { }
```

Consequently, there is a controller for DocumentFileData and one for WatermarkFileData to access the proper database table for each type of data. However, all underlying operations are identical. So I hope to able to solve this via a generic class to save me the trouble of having to make identical changes to two different classes everytime something in file data handling changes.

Comment: That’s generics. Not dynamic

Comment: If all classes have an Id of the same type - introduce base class/interface.

Comment: Actually I need two different tables in a database with the exact same structure. So my db context has two different db sets with the exact same underlying data structure. To make the controller properly access the right table, I need two different data types, even if they share the same base class. I cannot think of a better way to implement that than via a generic class (not saying there wouldn't be a better way).

Comment: @Daniel A. White: Fixed the title

Comment: @Guru Stron: Doesn't work. See my update to my question.

Comment: The errors are listed at comments in my code samples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you have an common interface exposing `ID` property provide corresponding generic constraint - (you need to specify both generic type constraints - interface and `class`):

```cs
public class FileDataController<T> : ODataController where T : class, IFileData
```

Comment: Bingo! That did the trick, thank you.

Comment: Won't just doing `where T: FileData` work in the code @Razzupaltuff has shown though?  With no need for an interface?

Comment: @RichN yes, it would, but personally I still prefer using the interfaces.

Comment: @Rich N: Wouldn't that boil down to omitting the generic parameter T altogether, making T always be FileData?

Comment: @Razzupaltuff you can't omit the `T` since you are using it in `_context.Set<T>` (`T` will be determined at the compile time). But limiting `T` to `FileData` is completely fine though.

Answer (score 1):

As @GuruSiton correctly commented, you should introduce an interface with `ID` in it:

```
interface IClassWithId
{
    Guid ID { get; } // Notice that you only require get - the implementer can choose how the ID get init'd - private / c'tor / etc
}

public class FileDataController<T> : ODataController where T : IClassWithId
{ ... }
```

This assumes that you can make - or require - all classes used as T to implement `IClassWithId`. If you're stuck with existing classes that define their own ID and can't change them, then you must resort to reflection, as hinted to by @NaeemAhmed.

Comment: Actually my classes all share the same base class. I am just required to keep semantically different data of the exact same structure in different tables (the tables store requirement documents and watermark data, and I am required to keep them apart). I am using Blazor, code first, and to make it generate and handle two different tables, I need two different classes ... but basically only one controller class. I need to look into interfaces more; I am pretty new to C# (C++ veteran), and I am not too familiar with that concept.

Comment: When I introduce an interface IFileData, add a class FileData : IFileData, change my classes to something like WatermarkFileData : FileData, and the controller to FileDataController<T> : ODataController where T : IFileData, I cannot access the table in the db set anymore: Calling _context.Set<T>() yields error #CS0452.

Comment: C# interface are similar to C++ pure abstract classes, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/318064). For your problem, see whether [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10376531/552510) answers your current issue

Comment: I had flagged the proper reply days ago already ...